# Does Google Analytics work for react-router-dom as well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I've just started learning React.js, and deployed my first project. I'm trying to use Google Analytics to track the user behavior in my website. But since React-Router-Dom lets pages switch to one another without refreshing each one, I'm not sure GA can still track the change of url. 
Does GA track the change, or do I have to use some other methods?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router nowadays gives you a hook to get its history object, and that history object has a method to attach a listener for when it changes.

This is what we’re going to use in our own hook: https://gist.github.com/jmagrippis/1cdaed8de5bec35888d31dd355e22302#file-usetracking-ts